# Python - Using index from tuple list, how to solve when index out of range only using while statement

Tags: python, list, indexing, while-loop, tuples

I made a while loop that :

1. Counts daily steps in a list of tuple
2. Returns the number of days taken for the aimed steps.
3. Must return None if the total steps are lower than the aimed steps.

This works fine until the index range exceeds the given list.

I've attempted various ways using If statement like below but couldn't make it work.. I found it works when I change the index value > Len(step_records) but seems it get error when the index value is += 1 from the while loop.

* I am not allowed to use for statement.

---

```
step_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',3)]

aim_steps = 7
total_steps = 0
index = 0
days = 0


if len(step_records) >= index:
    while total_steps < aim_steps:
        total_steps += step_records[index][1]
        index += 1
        days += 1    
    print(days)
else:
    days = None
    print(days)
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lowden/untitled-3.py", line 13, in <module>
    total_steps += step_records[index][1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you have hardcoded the `aim_steps` to 7 but there are only 3 records in `step_records` . what are you trying to do ?

Comment: please explain your input and what the output you want, then it will be helpful to solve, input is clear but not the output @PeterJeon

Comment: Sorry for the lack information..   step_records = (date, number of steps) and I want to return the number of days it took to reach or exceed the aim_steps . If the aim_steps are not reached the given list of tuples I want to return None, which means aim is not reached yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your problem is that you check whether `index` is greater than `len(step_records)` only once. Then you enter a while loop, that has no checks whether the has `index` already exceeded the `len(step_records)`. That is, once you're inside the `if` statement, no more `len(step_records) >= index` checks are being done, and after 3 iterations you get an error (when `index` becomes 3, whereas maximum index of `step_records` is only 2).

You could try something like this:

```
...

while len(step_records) > index:
    if total_steps < aim_steps:
        total_steps += step_records[index][1]
        days += 1    
    index += 1
...
```

With this code, each iteration you'd check whether the `index` is still less than the total size of your list. If you eventually exceed `aim_steps`, you just iterate until `index` is larger than `len(step_records)`. Or you could just as well add an `else` condition with `break` inside it, so that you break out of the loop immediately.

Unlike some of the other solutions, this should not hang when different step values (i.e., all 1) are inputted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your explanation really helped me understand further.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
while total_steps < aim_steps:
    if index < len(step_records):
        total_steps += step_records[index][1]
        index += 1
        days += 1
print(days)
```

I'm not fully sure I'm understanding your problem, but this would keep you from getting an index out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

The best practices to loop over a sequence is not to use index. You can iterate the sequence.

Your code can be simplified:

```
step_records = [('2010-01-01', 1),
                ('2010-01-02', 2),
                ('2010-01-03', 3)]

total_steps = 0
days = 0

for record in step_records:
    total_steps += record[1]
    days += 1

print(total_steps)
# -> 6
print(days)
# -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace -- while total_steps < aim_steps:

By -- while total_steps < aim_steps and index < len(step_records):

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.. With the advises I solved it buy doing below...

```
def days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, n):
    """Number of days taken to reach the aimed n steps"""


    total_steps = 0
    index = 0    
    days = 0


    while total_steps < n and index < len(step_records):

        total_steps += step_records[index][1]
        index += 1
        days += 1    

        if total_steps < n and index >= len(step_records):
            days = None        




    return days

step_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',3)]

days = days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, 6)
'''Aim_step is reached in 3 days so returns 6'''

days = days_to_reach_n_steps(step_records, 15)
'''Aim_step is not reached so returns None'''

print(days)
```

Again, thanks!